# Selecting by two parameters from table

Tags: php, postgresql

i have a HTML form where i can find a book by author in the URL address.

the url goes like this: http://mywebsite.com/books/?author=john+smith
and it retrieves me book(s).

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  doc_documents.id doc_id, 
  doc_documents.projection_isbd doc_isbd
FROM 
  doc_documents 
  LEFT JOIN doc_document_authors ON doc_document_authors.document_id = doc_documents.id 
  LEFT JOIN usr_users ON usr_users.id = doc_document_authors.user_id 
WHERE 
  doc_documents.status = 'CONFIRMED' AND
  db_type = 'PDB' AND
  deleted = 'f' AND
  usr_users.title ilike $1
ORDER BY
  doc_documents.publish_date desc
```

where $1 parameter comes from PHP script, where i exctract from URL GET parameter.

The problem is where i try to find books where are two (or more) authors in the url, i. e.:

http://mywebsite.com/books/?author=john+smith&author2=william+lother

i tried my sql like this:

```
SELECT 
      doc_documents.id doc_id, 
      doc_documents.projection_isbd doc_isbd
    FROM 
      doc_documents 
      LEFT JOIN doc_document_authors ON doc_document_authors.document_id = doc_documents.id 
      LEFT JOIN usr_users ON usr_users.id = doc_document_authors.user_id 
    WHERE 
      doc_documents.status = 'CONFIRMED' AND
      db_type = 'PDB' AND
      deleted = 'f' AND
      (usr_users.title ilike $1 AND
       usr_users.title ilike $2)
    ORDER BY
      doc_documents.publish_date desc
```

but it wont work.
can you help me to write an sql?

Comment: *it wont work*: yes, because you're expecting to a single user's name (title) to be matched against 2 (or more) patterns; which will not happen (unless the patterns are somewhat similar to each other). what you really need is to join your tables (`doc_document_authors` and `usr_users`) as many times as author filters are in the query, & then search for `WHERE usr_users1.title ilike $1 AND usr_users2.title ilike $2 AND ...`

Comment: Tried this, but it didint work, i done this by this SQL: [SELECT
 *
FROM
elaba.doc_documents
LEFT JOIN elaba.doc_document_authors ON doc_document_authors.document_id = doc_documents.id
LEFT JOIN elaba.usr_users as auth1 ON auth1.id = doc_document_authors.user_id
LEFT JOIN elaba.usr_users as auth2 ON auth2.id = doc_document_authors.user_id
LEFT JOIN elaba.usr_users as auth3 ON auth3.id = doc_document_authors.user_id
WHERE
 doc_documents.status = 'CONFIRMED' AND
 db_type = 'PDB' AND
 deleted = 'f' AND
 (auth1.title ilike 'Jhon Smith' and auth2.title ilike 'John Doe')]

Comment: you need to join `doc_document_authors` multiple times as well (your query is still filter for the same author, but now joined multiple times).

Comment: Thanks, this one worked like a charm, this is what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expecting to a single user's name (title) to be matched against 2 (or more) patterns; which will not happen (unless the patterns are somewhat similar to each other).

What you need to do (in general) is to join different users (who are different authors of course) and filter them separately:

```
SELECT    doc_documents.id doc_id,
          doc_documents.projection_isbd doc_isbd
FROM      doc_documents
JOIN      doc_document_authors author1 ON author1.document_id = doc_documents.id
JOIN      doc_document_authors author2 ON author2.document_id = doc_documents.id
JOIN      usr_users user1 ON user1.id = author1.user_id
JOIN      usr_users user2 ON user2.id = author2.user_id
WHERE     doc_documents.status = 'CONFIRMED'
AND       db_type = 'PDB'
AND       NOT deleted
AND       (user1.title ilike $1 AND user2.title ilike $2)
ORDER BY  doc_documents.publish_date desc
```

This is of course hard to generalize when you have to do this filtering N times.

Another possibility is to use some [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) in aggregation:

```
SELECT    doc_documents.id doc_id,
          doc_documents.projection_isbd doc_isbd
FROM      doc_documents
JOIN      doc_document_authors ON doc_document_authors.document_id = doc_documents.id
JOIN      usr_users ON usr_users.id = doc_document_authors.user_id
WHERE     doc_documents.status = 'CONFIRMED'
AND       db_type = 'PDB'
AND       NOT deleted
GROUP BY  doc_documents.id -- this will only work when id is the primary key
                           -- otherwise use the primary key of doc_documents
                           -- or doc_documents.*
HAVING    bool_or(usr_users.title ilike $1)
AND       bool_or(usr_users.title ilike $2)
ORDER BY  doc_documents.publish_date desc
```

This will ensure that each `usr_users.title ilike $N` expression will be (at least 1 time) `true` among all of the authors for each document.

Also note, that because you filter for `usr_users` in `WHERE` there is no point to use `LEFT JOIN` -- your filter will force an `INNER JOIN` (or `JOIN` in short) anyway.

Comment: Thank you, i will try the second solution, although, first one worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

can you try like this ?

```
SELECT 
  doc_documents.id doc_id, 
  doc_documents.projection_isbd doc_isbd
FROM 
  doc_documents 
  LEFT JOIN doc_document_authors ON doc_document_authors.document_id = doc_documents.id 
  LEFT JOIN usr_users ON usr_users.id = doc_document_authors.user_id 
WHERE 
  doc_documents.status = 'CONFIRMED' AND
  db_type = 'PDB' AND
  deleted = 'f' AND
  (usr_users.title ilike $1) OR
  (usr_users.title ilike $2)
ORDER BY
  doc_documents.publish_date desc
```

Comment: Yes i tried, but that is not the case, i would like to find both authors wich write the same. Get all the books, where are both authors write it. There also can be books what wrote three or four authors, as long as i enter in the URL address, i want to get that book.

Comment: you can use server side scripting language to build a query, and then after that you can fire it.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
(usr_users.title ilike $1 OR usr_users.title ilike $2)
```

instead of

```
(usr_users.title ilike $1 AND usr_users.title ilike $2)
```

?

Comment: No, i would like to find both authors write the same book. Authors count can be 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t is just because `LIKE` and `ILIKE` parameters must be enclosed into `%` character to match a part of the string ? You can also try with the regular expression match operator `~` and `~*` (for case insensitive search), it does not have to use the `%` to match

`WHERE (usr_users.title ~* $1) AND (usr_users.title ~* $2)`

*Note:* the `deleted` field should be boolean or timestamptz instead of a useless char, the SQL query becomes more expressive that way:

`WHERE … AND NOT deleted AND …` (boolean) or `WHERE … AND deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND …` (timestamptz).